# Twitter Filtered DM

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm currently trying to write a script to send dm's to my followers who have certain keywords in their bio's.

I already wrote a script in js that will follow everybody who has a certain keyword in their bio.(with the profile card element visible on page)

Any idea where I should start guys?

Comment: Separate whatever functionality you have that filters your followers with the given keyword(s) into a separate function or method.  Then use that function inside your following function as well as use it in your new DM function.  [Stay DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with followers/list endpoint. Collect your followers data (maybe in database), then filter by keywords and send dm's.